# How do I create a View from couchbase Java sdk 2.1

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view, couchbase-java-api

I need to create a view with a map function ex:

```
function(doc, meta) {
  if(doc.docType == "testDoc")
    emit(meta.id, doc)
}
```

I have to create this view using couchbase java client 2.1.I could not find any thing in the documentation thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some code to create a design document:

```
List<View> viewsForCurrentDesignDocument = new ArrayList<View>();
DesignDocument designDocument = DesignDocument.create("my_design_doc", viewsForCurrentDesignDocument);
```

And add a view:

```
String mapFunction =
    "function (doc, meta) {\n" +
    "  if(doc.docType == \"testDoc\") {\n" +
    "    emit(meta.id, doc);\n" +
    "  }\n" +
    "}";

String reduceFunction = "..."  // or null if no reduce

View v = DefaultView.create("my_view", mapFunction, reduceFunction);
viewsForCurrentDesignDocument.add(v);
bucket.bucketManager().insertDesignDocument(designDocument);
```

You can check the [API reference](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.1.4/com/couchbase/client/java/bucket/BucketManager.html) for more options(development mode, timeout, ...).

Comment: note that the reduce function should just be left out / null if unused